# How to join two tables for sum in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in my postgresql database.

```
Table1
----------------------------------------
id      group_id        amount      size
1       1                 10        L
2       2                 20        M
3       2                 80        M



Table2
-------------------------------
id      group_id        amount
1       1               10
2       2               50 
3       2               60
```

The tables have a "groups" table relation with group_id as the key. And I want to get a sum table for amounts.

```
SumQueryResult
----------------------------------------
group_id    table_1_sum     table_2_sum
1             10            100
2             100           110
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need:

```
SELECT t1.GROUP_ID as group_id
       , sum(t1.AMOUNT) as table_1_sum
       , sum(t2.amount) as table_2_sum
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.GROUP_ID
order by t1.GROUP_ID;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2ab64bd585663df3b489e1bc0b9f41f9)

Cheers!

And here is the correct version of the Zaynul Abadin Tuhin answer:

```
select a.group_id
       , a.amt as tableamnt
       , b.amt as table2amt from (
select group_id,sum(amount) as amt from table1 group by group_id 
) a join (    
select group_id,sum(amount) as amt from table2 group by group_id 
) b on a.group_id=b.group_id
order by group_id
```

Here is the second [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=385fa1bce9a7b7d4749419df9e9f7b17)

Comment: But query takes so many times. There is a performance problem.

Comment: @barteloma i just forgot to add group by :)

Answer (score 0):

use subquery and join

```
select a.group_id,a.amt as tableamnt,b.amt as table2amt from (
select group_id,sum(amount) as amt from table1 group by group_id
) a join (    
select group_id,sum(amount) as amt from table2 group by group_id
) b on a.group_id=b.group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do 2 subquerys to group data by group_id and then join the 2 subquerys. Something like this:

```
SELECT group_id, table_1_sum, table_2_sum from (

   SELECT
      group_id,
      SUM(amount) as table_1_sum
   FROM
      Table1
   GROUP BY
      group_id;

INNER JOIN

   SELECT
      group_id,
      SUM(amount) as table_2_sum
   FROM
      Table2
   GROUP BY
       group_id;

ON Table1.group_id = Table2.group_id
)
```

Comment: Hi @xero399, you have more than one mistakes like `;` after individual selects, also when you remove that then you will have to give alias to that selects, and then you will have to say from what select do you want your group_id to be becaus there are two of them - one in each select. Also a order by would be nice. Here you can check the correct query:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=143b01d57a4cf75b24165c016325279f

Comment: thanks for the corrections and the example @VBokšić
Sorry, obviously I didn't tested it. Was only for give an idea of a possible solution.

Answer (score -1):

**I modified @Zaynul's query to be correct and work in postgresql.**

You want to sum the amount of each table separately by grouping group_id.
So, you cannot use JOIN query directly.

You must query and sum each table separately first.
Then join the results of previous queries.

The SQL Syntax will be like this :

```
SELECT a.group_id, a.amt as table_1_sum, b.amt as table_2_sum FROM (
    SELECT group_id, SUM(amount) as amt FROM table1 GROUP BY group_id
) a join (    
    SELECT group_id, SUM(amount) as amt FROM table2 GROUP BY group_id
) b ON a.group_id = b.group_id
```

I already tested in pgAdmin4 and got the result you want.

```
SumQueryResult
----------------------------------------
group_id    table_1_sum     table_2_sum
1             10            10(this can't be 100)
2             100           110
```

Comment: @barteloma but this is already in my answer(my second query -  also a modification of  Zaynul's query)? I do not understand. This is the same query. And you have a demo for both of those...